# In Diablo 3, what does "X Damage over Y Seconds" mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

For instance:  the power "Energy Twister" says it does 360% damage over 6 seconds.  Does this mean it does 360% for 6 seconds, or 60% per second for 6 seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easily put, it means it does X% of damage over a period of Y seconds. Meaning to get 1s of Damage dealt, you have to do **X/Y = [DMG]ps**

P.S - For an afterthought, according to your example, **360% per 6 seconds**, if it was 360% per 1s, that would be a total 2160% damage after 6s. Yeowch! (But overpowered much?)

Comment: Just as a sidenote, the actual number of ticks that the damage is broken into should be based on your weapon attack speed.  Faster speed means more "ticks" that do less damage each.

Comment: I guess 2160 would seem overpowered if the path was predictable.  As it stands though you're lucky to get the twister to sit on an enemy for 2 seconds therefore effectively capping the output at 120%

Comment: I was kind of hoping that someone would tell me the former case was true, otherwise I think pretty much all of the wizard DoTs are pointless

Comment: Its not exactly pointless if you can use a effective combo to keep the enemy in place/direct where you want him to go. But that's another story. If you're satisfied with the answer, could you accept it? It would close this chapter (and onwards to another question if you have any)

Comment: most of these effects aren't very good because they don't stack

Comment: It's probably worth noting that there are several abilities that do damage "for" a period of time rather than over - e.g. Grasp of the Dead does 20% damage "for" 8 seconds, for a total of 160%.  This is also the situation where no duration is mentioned, for example the Gargantuan/Hydra where it just says "Deals 25%/28% weapon damage".